# SSL and google chrome not secure warning

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, ssl

I have recently installed SSL certificate on our web app.

I am using Cloudflare and SSL certificate provided by them and have turned on Always use https mode there. All HTTP links are converted to https.

First screen, login

As I login, it changes to

https://demo.aonesalons.com

and along with https, Google marks it as insecure in the URL.

Even more surprising, I open the same link, the same window in a new tab, chrome does not show it as insecure. I am using angularJS application served by apache server.

What can I possibly change to prevent google chrome from marking this as insecure? Also, I am using service-worker in my application ( That's the reason I installed SSL on the app)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check If your page contains a request wich require **http** protocol example html wich contains:

`<a href="http://github.com">
      Not secure
 </a>`

**Fix**


`<a href="https://github.com">
   Secure
</a>`

**How to check**
Open Chrome devtools and search window "Network", in this search the urls wich your web load and replace the urls http by https.

[Google DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBa1j.jpg)

Comment: I did. None of the resources are being served over http. Also, why would it show not secure in one tab and secure in another?

Comment: Can you post images? Please

Comment: I would have but with in a coupe of minutes, without any changes, chromw returns net: err failed for all API calls. Can you please check console here for link: demo.aonesalons.com

Comment: I tried clearing all browser storage and service worker but nothing worked. it is not even hitting the server but returning this error already

Comment: In my phone I see this: https://i.imgur.com/ulE73HB.png
Update your browser cache ^^

Comment: If you use cdn for example cloudflare purge cache save setting, else wait 24 hours for update your web server

Comment: That's right. If you will go to the console in browser, you should be able to see net:: ERR_FAILED for all API calls.

Comment: Also, I tried to purge cache from Cloudflare, nothing changed

Comment: Wait this hours cloudflare is very slowy, If the error is persistent try disable js minify in cloudflare or the rocketloader.

Comment: Tried that as well. Still nothing "(

Comment: in my case, an image was loaded from http. switching it to https solved it